# Get shipping and billing information from rule

Tags: rules, commerce

I am using the Drupal commerce module. I want to write a PHP script to execute on order completion, and I want that script to update an external database with the shipping information. How would I go about doing this?

I have already setup a rule to execute PHP code on order completion, and I am given the variable `$commerce_order`, but I don't know what to call to get out the customer shipping information. I have tried to email `var_dump($commerce_order)` but it does not give me anything.

How can I get a list of the fields? Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shipping information isn't directly stored on the order. The only way you have of figuring the shipping details is to look at the line items at `$order->commerce_line_items` one or more of them will be shipping line items, which can tell you about the shipping details.

Comment: How can I figgure out what is in `$order->commerce_line_items`?

Answer (score 0):

To write to a second DB you most likely need some custom code. Therfore I sugest to write your own rules action (see http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!rules!rules.api.php/function/hook_rules_action_info/7)

I'd start with the 'order is payed in full' rules event since it gives you the order and payment transaction object in the $data parameter of the action.

Have a look at the commerce_email module to get a code example for finding the line items of an order.